# Questions about pointers and arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a question about this simple program in C to practice with pointers and arrays.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

fun(int *p, int *v) {
    *p++;
    *(v+2) = p[3];
    *v++ = p[0];
    v[0] = *(p+4);
}

int main() {

    int v[] = {90, 89, 8, 78, 60, 120};
    int k[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int *ptr = k;

    fun(v, ptr);
    for (ptr = k; ptr < k + 6; ptr++)
        printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

So my question is why it prints `89 120 60 0 0 0`.

Comment: Are you familiar with how a debugger works? Step over each statement and inspect the values.

Comment: Or just remember that stuff does things in C because you told it to. :)

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Check out pointer arithmetic. It's basically what you might be confused about here. http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Comment: That is not a "simple program".  That program is *needlessly complicated*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's useful to draw out (even by hand on paper!) what's going on with pointers and arrays. For the following function:

```
void fun(int *p, int *v) {
    *p++;
    *(v+2) = p[3];
    *v++ = p[0];
    v[0] = *(p+4);
}
```

You have passed these arrays:

```
[90] [89] [8] [78] [60] [120]
 |
 p

[0]  [0]  [0] [0]  [0]  [0]
 |
 v
```

What happens in `fun`?

```
*p++
```

This could be read one of two ways: Dereference p and (post) increment that value, or post-increment p and dereference the old value of p.  Which is it? Our handy table of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) says ++ comes before *, so it's the second one.  Notice that we deference a pointer, but don't do anything the value. That means we could have written `p++` and gotten the same result.

After the increment, our pointer has changed:

```
[90] [89] [8] [78] [60] [120]
      |
      p
```

The next line uses both `p` and `v`:

```
    *(v+2) = p[3];
```

You can read this as "assign the 3rd value to the right of p to the 2nd spot to the right of v."  The third spot to the right of p has `60`, and it goes here:

```
[0]  [0]  [60] [0]  [0]  [0]
 |
 v
```

Next up:

```
*v++ = p[0];
```

From before, we know that *v++ means (post) increment v. The difference between ++v (pre-increment) and v++ (post-increment) is what value gets returned - in this case, we'll modify v but use its old value, assiging what p is pointing at. Notice that v has been incremented:

```
[89]  [0]  [60] [0]  [0]  [0]
       |
       v
```

And finally:

```
v[0] = *(p+4);
```

This can be read as "assign th e 4th value to the right of p to the 0th spot to the right of v." The forth spot to the right of p has 120, and it goes here:

```
[89]  [120]  [60] [0]  [0]  [0]
       |
       v
```

So at the end of the function, this is what our pointers and memory look like:

```
[90] [89] [8] [78] [60] [120]
 |    |
 |    p
main-v

[89]  [120]  [60] [0]  [0]  [0]
 |     |
 |     v
main-k
main-ptr
```